# How to pass the second parameter in function?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Here is a code:

```
new VectorLayer({
        source: clusterSource,
        zIndex: Infinity,
        style: styleFunction
      });

export const styleFunction = (cluster: any) => {}
```

I want to pass the second parameter for modifyed function:

```
export const styleFunction = (cluster: any, options: any) => {}
```

I have tried:

```
  style: styleFunction(this, { icon, text })
```

Comment: You are passing the second parameter correctly. What error are you running into? Is the issue that you need `style` to be the function, and not the return value of the function?

Comment: It is openlayers function

Comment: Could you share how `VectorLayer` uses `style`? If you need to pass a function you might just need to do: `() => styleFunction(this, { icon, text })`

Comment: I have found this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html

Comment: I solved this using: `     style: styleFunction.bind( { icon, text }),`

Comment: Great! `.bind` creates a new function, and should be similar to using a new inline function as I suggested. Both are correct.

Comment: Sorry, it does not, in funciton I get value but another I passed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248767/discussion-between-alina-and-matthew-herbst).

Comment: So the right way is: `        style: (cluster) => {
          return styleCluster(cluster, { image });
        },`